# Nextjs getServerSideProps does not pass session to component

Tags: reactjs, session, next.js, next-auth

Good morning. I am using NextJS and get the session in the `getServerSideProps` block.
I am passing multiple parameters to the return object, however, the session does not pass. All of the other key value pairs works, but when I try to log the session, It comes undefined... I don't understand...

```
const DashboardPage = ({ session, secret }) => {

  const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);

  //This does not work
  console.log('Session: ', session);

  return (
    <section className="border-4 border-orange-800 max-w-5xl mx-auto">
      
      <CreateListModal userId={session?.userId} loading={loading} setloading={setloading} />
    </section>
  )
}





export const getServerSideProps = async context => {

  // get sessions with added user Id in the session object
  const session = await requireAuthentication(context);

// This works
  console.log(session);


  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/signup',
        permanent: false
      }
    }
  }
  
  else {
    return {
      props: {

        session: session,
        secret: 'Pasarika este dulce'
      }
    }
  }
}

export default DashboardPage;
```

The purpose of the `requireAuthentication` function is to create a new session object where I will insert another key value pair that will contain the user id and the session that will be used in the entire app.

In that function I get the user by email that is returned by the session and get the Id from the db. I than return the new session object that looks like this:

```
{
  user: {
    name: 'daniel sas',
    email: 'email@gmail.com',
    image: 'https://lh3.googldeusercontent.com/a/A6r44ZwMyONqcfJORNnuYtbVv_LYbab-wv5Uyxk=s96-c',
    userId: 'clbcpc0hi0002sb1wsiea3q5d'//This is the required thing in my app
  },
  expires: '2022-12-23T08:04:08.263Z'
}
```

The following function is used to get the data from the database

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import prisma from './prisma'

// This function get the email and returns a new session object that includes 
//  the userId

export const requireAuthentication = async context => {
    const session = await getSession(context);


    // If there is no user or there is an error ret to signup page
    if (!session) return null

    // If the user is not found return same redirect to signup
    else {
        try {
            const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({where: { email: session.user.email }});
            
            if (!user) return null;

            // Must return a new session here that contains the userId...
            else {
              const newSession = {
                user: {
                  ...session.user,
                  userId: user.id
                },

                expires: session.expires
              };

              return newSession;
            }
        } 
        catch (error) {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you `console.log("secret",secret)` inside DashboardPage

Comment: Yes. that works just fine... But the session is undefined

Comment: that i smight be the serialization issue from.  send `session:JSON.stringify(session)` and parse it in the page

Comment: I tried also. 
Update: 
- It looks like nextjs 'session' variable is a reserved word. ```props: {
        newSession: session,
        secret: 'Pasarika este dulce'
      }
```

I changed the key value and now worked...